# Select clause from two different table

Tags: sql, sqlplus

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.D#,DEPARTMENT.DNAME,DEPARTMENT.MANAGER#
FROM DEPARTMENT,PROJECT
WHERE DEPARTMENT.D# <> PROJECT.D#;
```

when this code run in SQL plus, a lot repeated output come out, my output should be
one time only.

Comment: What do you select from table PROJECT?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is something that you want, but if you want only those departments that do not have any projects use

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.D#,DEPARTMENT.DNAME,DEPARTMENT.MANAGER#
   FROM DEPARTMENT
      WHERE DEPARTMENT.D# not in (select PROJECT.D# from project);
```

Hope it Helps

Vishad

Comment: work . but the output still repeat. 
it's just like looping then keep output those data that already been displayed

Comment: then it looks like you have duplicate data in your department table. Did you try using distinct in Select ?

Answer (score 0):

Use as

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.D#,DEPARTMENT.DNAME,DEPARTMENT.MANAGER#
  FROM DEPARTMENT,PROJECT
  WHERE DEPARTMENT.D# != PROJECT.D#;
```

Comment: it's same in sql that != and <>